# What is the root of an utterance without a verb?

Tags: roots, dependency-grammar

Dependency grammars treat the main verb of a sentence as the root node of a dependency graph. Not all utterances, however, have verbs. (Example: the widely known exclamation "holy shit!")

In these types of phrases, what would be considered the root of the phrase from a dependency perspective?

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies are not restricted to verbs and their dependents, rather they exist between all types of nodes. On a conventional understanding, the **root** is *the one node that is not dominated by one of the other nodes*.
In your example, then noun **shit** is the root, because **holy**, the only other node available, does not dominate it.
Dependencies are typed, i.e. subclassified. For instance, attributive adjectives, such as **white** in *white horses*, depend on their nouns. Hence **holy** should depend on **shit**.
The *Stanford Dependencies* take this to be an **amod** (adjectival modifier) dependency. ([The 2008 paper "Stanford typed dependencies manual"](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~mcdm/publications.html) lists common dependencies from section 2 on).
[*Meaning-Text-Theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning%E2%80%93text_theory) (MTT) labels branches between nodes with syntactic functions. For an example see [Wikipedia: Dependency grammar: Syntactic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar#Syntactic_functions). The dependency between an adjective and a noun is called **attr**(ibutive) in MTT.

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't quite answered my question. Would a root node be at play here at all? Or is this function reserved purely for verbs.

Comment: So if you amend your answer to include this, I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: @Sibutlasi. I don't understand your comment. It's clearly critical of dependency grammars, but its not a coherent criticism. What do you mean? Expand a little on your criticism.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out yourself using [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) library.  Install the Python library:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then in Python

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("holy shit!")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
            token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

And you'll get this output (note `shit` has the dependency tag of `ROOT` and `holy` has a dependency tag of `amod` which is as Thomas Gross predicted).

```
holy holy PROPN NNP amod xxxx True False
shit shit PROPN NNP ROOT xxxx True False
! ! PUNCT . punct ! False False
```